# Query data from sqlite database and set to edittext and textview

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I pass data from another activity and use for args in querying in my database and I would like to query some data in my sqlite database and set it to edittext and textview. But it display nothing. When I check if there's some data been queried it return true. Please help

Here's the code in my first activity when clicking item on listview and passing data to another activity

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
        view, int position, long id) {
        TextView temp = (TextView) view; 
        Intent i = new Intent(home.this, Update.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("sulod", temp.getText().toString());
        Pig pig = new Pig();
        pig.pig_type = temp.getText().toString();
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Code in my second activity

```
public void display(){
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String sulod = bundle.getString("sulod");
    Cursor c = myDb.filList();
    String sremarks = "";
    String saddress = "";
    int Id = 0;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String name = c.getString(1);
        if(name == sulod){
            Id = c.getInt(0);
            sremarks = c.getString(2);
            saddress = c.getString(3);
        }
    }
    id.setText(Id+"");
    remarks.setText(sremarks);
    address.setText(saddress);
}
```

And in my dbhelper

```
public Cursor filList() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4};
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null,
    null, null);
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably that `name == sulod` tests to see if they're the same object, not that their values are the same (you want `name.equals( sulod )` -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2096401). Also, would it not be better to pass `sulod` into the `filList()` function and have SQLite use it in a `WHERE` clause instead of filtering manually?